# Two "volatile" variables in the constructor follow Happens-before relationship?

Tags: java, concurrency, java.util.concurrent, concurrenthashmap, concurrent-programming

Here's an example of `ConcurrentHashMap` in Java7:

```
static final class HashEntry<K,V> {
final int hash;
final K key;
volatile V value;
volatile HashEntry<K,V> next;

HashEntry(int hash, K key, V value, HashEntry<K,V> next) {
    this.hash = hash;
    this.key = key;
    this.value = value;
    this.next = next;
}
```

So if a thread sees the `next` field, is it guaranteed that the `value` field is not `null`?

---

**update**:

So if I constrain that in my tests the `value` can not be modified after initialization, and `null` value cannot be assigned by the constructor, threads which take `next` to get `HashEntry` will never see `value` as `null`?

Comment: volatile doesn't transform null into non-null. It guarantees the the value is visible to other threads, whether the value if null or not.

Comment: Broadly speaking, thread safety encompasses two things: visibility and atomicity.  The `volatile` declaration accounts for visibility, but cannot guarantee atomicity (which is generally provided by mutual exclusion).  The `volatile` keyword still leaves you susceptible to race conditions in situations where state transitions require mutating more than one field.  In the case of `ConcurrentHashMap`, advanced techniques such as striping and cooperativity are used to keep the need for mutual exclusion to a minimum while preserving atomicity.

Answer (score 1):

In the presented constructor code, assignment to `value` will always be seen as having happened before the assignment to `next`. However, you must be very careful when reasoning about invariants in concurrent code. There may be other threads concurrently executing other code which assigns to `value`. Since your question already assumes that the instance was published to other threads, it can be next to impossible to ensure there are no other writers.

Finally, note that `value` may actually be assigned `null` at the outset, given the presented code.

Answer (score 0):

Cited from [Atomic Access](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html)(highlight is mine):

> Using volatile variables reduces the risk of memory consistency errors, because any *write* to a volatile variable establishes a happens-before relationship with subsequent *reads* of that **same variable**. This means that changes to a volatile variable are always visible to other threads. What's more, it also means that when a thread reads a volatile variable, it sees not just the latest change to the volatile, but also the side effects of the code that led up the change.

As you can see, `happens-before relationship` is for same variable.

Thanks @JBNizet's reminder.

The 'side effects' for `next` can be the code assign to `value`. But it just mean the thread will see the `value` not gurantee that other threads will not set `value` to other value including `null`.

Comment: As you can see, **it also means that when a thread reads a volatile variable, it sees not just the latest change to the volatile, but also the side effects of the code that led up the change**.

Comment: It seems to. But Marko's answer is much clearer than yours.

Answer (score 0):

Consider how the constructor is invoked:

```
myHashEntry = new HashEntry(hash, key, value, next);
```

myHashEntry is not set until the constructor has run to completion. There is no other reference to the object available while the constructor is still running. So there is no way for another thread to concurrently look inside a partially constructed object.

Comment: I cannot agree with you. I think the memory model is not defined as you mentioned.

Comment: How can a thread access the fields of an object when there is not yet any reference to that object?

Comment: There is one way.  It doesn't apply to the example given, but it's a common enough mistake.  If a constructor gives away `this` to some other thread, the the other thread potentially could access the object before the constructor call returns.  In that case, Java does _not_ guarantee that the initial values of any of the object's fields will be immediately visible to the other thread.

Comment: I just did an experiment with that - I was able to access a final int before it had been assigned. It had a value of zero but I guess that's not guaranteed either.